# Is it possible make filter pass additional value to map in scala?

Tags: scala

Is it possible make `filter` pass an additional value to `map` in Scala?

```
myList.filter { e =>
    val anotherVal = someFun(e)
    someFun2(anotherVal) != 'error'
}.map {
    val anotherVal = someFun(e)
    someFun3(antherVal)
}
```

I'm calling `someFun(e)` twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `flatMap`:

```
myList.flatMap { e =>
    val anotherVal = someFun(e)
    if(someFun2(anotherVal) != 'error') {
        Some(someFun3(anotherVal))
    }
    else None
}
```

Comment: flatMap all the things +1!

Comment: I find the use of `flatMap` feels somewhat hacky or dirty in this case. You implicitly encode a filtering by the construction of `Option`s, which distracts from the point of your code. There are better alternatives in functional programming.

Answer (score 4):

Using a for comprehension, like this,

```
for { 
    e <- myList;
    anotherVal = someFun(e) if someFun2(anotherVal) != 'error';
} yield someFun3(antherVal)
```

**Update** This is in fact syntactic sugar for `flatMap`, yet this syntax may show the code somehow concisely.

Answer (score 2):

The method `collect` is `filter` combine `map`:

```
myList collect ( x => someFun(x) match {
      case y if someFun2(y) != "error" => someFun3(y)
  })
```

For example:

```
scala> val xs = 1 to 36
xs: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3, .., 36)

scala> def f1(x: Int): Int = x/2
f1: (x: Int)Int

scala> def f2(x: Int): Int = x%3
f2: (x: Int)Int

scala> def f3(x: Int): Int = x*x
f3: (x: Int)Int

scala> xs collect (x => f1(x) match { case y if f2(y) == 1 => f3(y) })
res3: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 1, 16, 16, 49, 49, 100, 100, 169, 169, 256, 256)
```

Comment: This is not the right way to do collect. You shouldn't have to use a `match` statement with in the function passed into `collect`.

Comment: @DCKing I known your point. But I want to only use `collect` without `map` or `filter` and call `someFun` onece.

Answer (score 1):

As Eastsun said, `collect` is the function used to do filtering, casting and mapping at the same time. It accepts a *partial function* - a function that is only applied to *some* inputs that satisfy a certain condition. It then produces a new collection with only the results of that function.

In your case, you have a partial function that is only applied if `someFun2(anotherVal) != "error"`. Therefore, you can first use `map` on your original collection to do the first transformation from `e` to `anotherVal`. Then you can use `collect` to transform that collection. Your code could look like this:

```
myList.map(someFun).collect {
   case anotherVal if someFun2(anotherVal) != "error" =>
      someFun3(anotherVal)
}
```

Alternatively, you can just keep using `filter` like this.

```
myList.map(someFun)
      .filter(anotherVal => someFun2(anotherVal) != "error")
      .map(someFun3)
```

Which one you prefer depends on taste.

Comment: Good for the collect mention, but still does not answer the question. Where is `someFun(e)` gone to?

Comment: @maasg Good catch, skipped over that. Added it now.